# Finding suffixes in a set of strings, Python

Tags: python

Given an input - words as a set of strings - determine whether any of the words contained in the set are suffixes of other words in the set, returning True if so, and False if not.

Methods i have tried:

```
import re
def findsuffix(words_set):
    for i in words_set:
        x = re.compile('w*'+i)
        for j in words_set:
            while i != j:
                if x.search(j):
                    return True
                else
                    return False
```

I have also tried .endswith() option.

I am relatively new and still learning, i think it is iterating through the words set that i am having issues with. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The data structure you're look for is the intersection of two suffix trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endswith` would be fine—and a lot simpler, and probably even faster. But that's not the main problem with your code.

---

The first problem is here:

```
if x.search(j):
    return True
else
    return False
```

The first time you find a pair that isn't a match, you're going to `return False` immediately, without testing any other pairs of words. But you only want to `return False` if *all* pairs are not matches, not if *any* pair is not a match.

To fix this, just remove that `else` clause, and put a `return False` after the whole top-level loop.

---

But you have another problem you also have to fix:

```
while i != j:
```

Since you don't reassign or modify `i` or `j` anywhere in that loop, once `i != j` is true once, it'll be true forever. So, you're going to loop forever, testing the same two values.

What you want here is an `if` statement:

```
if i != j:
```

---

It would really help to learn how to debug your flow control. You can do quick&dirty debugging by adding lines like `print('About to check {}'.format(j))` in appropriate places, and seeing what gets printed out. But it's much better to learn to use the debugger, or an online visualizer like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, (with **O(n log n)** time complexity rather than **O(n*n)** ):

```
def findsuffix(word_set):
    ws = sorted(w[::-1] for w in word_set)
    return any(y.startswith(x) for x, y in zip(ws[:-1], ws[1:]))

findsuffix(['abcdef', '123', 'cdef'])
Out[1]: True

findsuffix(['abcdef', '123', 'cdefg'])
Out[2]: False
```

Comment: This looks interesting, could you please elaborate a little on the description? :)

Comment: My English is not good enough to describe it clear:(, I hope the code itself would do.

Comment: This really is very clever. @user3636636, the algorithm relies on the words in the word set being first reversed and then sorted. For 2 words with the same initial character sequence, the shorter one will sort before the longer one, and this results in a list in which adjacent items are candidates for having a matching prefix (which is actually the suffix because the words were reversed). It's then a matter of comparing adjacent words by zipping the sorted list an offset of itself, and checking the prefix using `startswith()`. The complexity for the sort is O(n log n), thus O(n log n) overall.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findsuffix(words_set):
    words_set = set(words_set)
    for i in words_set:
        for j in words_set:
            if i == j:
                continue
            if i.endswith(j) or j.endswith(i):
                return True
    return False
```